# What are the semantics of getting a EADDRINUSE when no listening socket is bound, but connections are open

Tags: linux, tcp, fork

Consider a parent process which completes a `socket/bind/accept`, and will fork children with that socket open for them to communicate with, while the parent continues accepting connections. That parent process is then killed.

Another process now attempts to bind to the same address the parent process was bound to, on the same port, but receives an EADDRINUSE error.

However, when you complete this process with `sshd`, it seems `sshd` *is* able to rebind to the port that was closed, while during the restart window (where the sshd parent process is not running), a different program (running as a different user) just gets EADDRINUSE.

What are the semantics behind this? Why can `sshd` rebind, but another users process cannot?

Additionally, I can confirm that the `netstat -a | grep PORT` output from during the time only the child process is running (when the other process can't `bind`), the only connection is the `ESTABLISHED` one, none in `LISTEN` state.

Comment: Look into `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Comment: @Patrick That doesn't explain why `sshd` apparently can rebind the port when another process can't.  However, an understanding of `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_LINGER`/linger time (see `man 7 socket`, and **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14388707/1151724)**) is probably necessary to filling in the details which might make this question answerable.  Right now methinks it is not.

Comment: @goldilocks sure it does. `sshd` is using `SO_REUSEADDR`, this other application isn't.

Comment: @Patrick Hmmm, I've always assumed that `SO_REUSEADDR` must be set by both the process which owned the now defunct socket *and* the new one...then I further assumed that the original process was coded by the OP in ignorance of SO_REUSEADDR.  But you're right, this is almost certainly the explanation; only the new process needs to use it and `sshd` did.

Comment: @Patrick Well, SO_REUSEADDR works, but man 7 socket doesn't do a good job of explaining what the 'issue' is here. Is the "reuse of a local address" part the relevant bit? Does it count as "reuse of a local address" if there's already a connection there, even though it's not "reusing" the bind/listen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't understand all of the semantics (I'm either looking in the wrong place, or the documentation is lacking), I believe that for a certain amount of time after closing a connection (perhaps set by `SO_LINGER`), no process can open a new socket with the same details unless they have `SO_REUSEADDR` set.

This is to prevent someone reconnecting a second after a connection is closed and the process having to deal with packets that were meant for the previous process, as I understand it.

`man 7 socket` doesn't document this as part of `SO_REUSEADDR` which made this answer hard to figure out.